# How to remove unnecessary tags?

Tags: python

I have field "body" in my table (mysql) and there a lot of entries like:

```
</p><p>  &nbsp;</p><p>

</p><p> 
   </p><p>
```

A lot of spaces, new line, &nbsp, etc. How to remove it?

This not work:

```
text.replace('</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>', '</p><p>')
text.replace('</p><p>\n</p><p>', '</p><p>')
```

Answer (score 2):

`text = ''.join(text.split())` - after that you can continue with your replacements.

Answer (score 1):

I would parse such a file in a syntax tree, and then removed there empty leaves. Then would generate the HTML file again.
Unfortunately I'm not working in python, I cannot specify the helpful libraries for this.

Comment: That would be the best way that would handle things like comments or attribute values containing "<p></p>" correctly. But in most cases a simple search and replace works, too.

Answer (score 1):

What @Jurlie Suggested is a Good approach.
Consider using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) for this purpouse. It is a very mature and robust library.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''</p><p>  &nbsp;</p><p>
... 
... </p><p> 
...    </p><p>
... '''
>>> re.sub(r'<p>(?:&nbsp;|\s|<br \/>)*?</p>\s*', '', text)
'</p><p>\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.strip('>&nbsp;').strip(' ').strip('\n').strip('\t')
```